# "Cannot resolve method" unable to access object methods inside a loop (passing object reference to function)

Tags: java, android, object, android-linearlayout

I'm new to Android and JAVA,... my Activity have many widgets that are inside separated LinearLayouts. I want to toggle them on and off accordingly. I have some radio buttons which will hide or show certain LinearLayouts as required. It makes more sense to me having the widgets grouped as sections for this case.

I'm having a problem accessing the methods "getVisibility" and "setVisibility" from inside a "for" loop. I'm using an array of Object type. I thought in maybe just pass the layouts id's as strings but something tells me it will not work.

As a side question : I have 13 total Linear Layouts in a single activity is it bad practice? I could not find a better way to horizontal align elements, maybe I took the short route? :p  Thanks in advance.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_job);

  ...

    LinearLayout monthlyContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.monthlyContainer);
    LinearLayout weeklyContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.weeklyContainer);
    LinearLayout fortnightlyContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fortnightlyContainer);
    LinearLayout fourweeklyContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fourweeklyContainer);
    LinearLayout twiceMonthlyContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.twiceMonthlyContainer);
    RadioGroup earningsContainer = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.earningsContainer);

    ///create a list of views to hide
    Object[] viewsToToggle={monthlyContainer, weeklyContainer, fortnightlyContainer, fourweeklyContainer, twiceMonthlyContainer, earningsContainer};



    //pass object array to hideView method
    this.hideView(viewsToToggle, monthlyContainer);

  ....

}



private void hideView(Object[] viewsToToggle, Object excludeMe){

    ///// create array to contain elements to toggle visibility


    Object[] viewstoHide = new Object[4];


    for(int i = 0; i < viewsToToggle.length; i++){

        if(viewsToToggle[i] != excludeMe){

            viewstoHide[i] =  viewsToToggle[i];
        }


    }


    for(int j = 0; j < viewstoHide.length; j++ ){

        if(viewstoHide[j].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){ //// syntax error on this line
            viewstoHide[j].setVisibility(View.GONE); //// syntax error on this line
        }


    }




    System.out.println("VIEWS TO HIDE : " + Arrays.toString(viewstoHide));



}
```

Comment: Your `viewstoHide` array does not contain ui elements, so you cannot use those metods. In order to use those methods, change the type of your array or add ui elements like `LinearLayouts`.

Comment: But my Ideia of having it as Object is because I could have multiple types in the array

Comment: This is causing you a problem. You cannot use those methods on any kind of objects, only on ui objects.

Comment: Yes I know, but what if I have Linear layouts and Radiogroups ? I just want to make the "hideView" method more abstract instead one for each type of ui Object

Comment: If you have `LinearLayout` and `Radiogroup` elements you'll be able to use those methods, because both are ui elements and the `setVisibility()` methos works correctly.

Comment: Right, but how would I declare the array type then? Object didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why the question was voted down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewstoHide` array does not contain ui elements, so you cannot use those methods. In order to use those methods, change the type of your array or add ui elements like `LinearLayout` or `Radiogroup`.

It's not a very good practice to add different types of ojects in your array because when you loop through the array of `objects` and you if want a to use a specific method on all elements, you can have only one different element and your loop will break. So in order to solve your problem, please use specific type for each array or add only ui elements. Good preactice is to verify if your elements are `instanceof` desired classes. Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem, any time. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the lights. It's true that there's a fine line between too much abstract and madness! xp

Answer (score 0):

Try making viewsToToggle an Array of LinearLayout instead of an Array of Object.

Same goes for viewsToHide.

Comment: It works, but what if I have multiple types, eg.  Linear layouts, Radiogroups. ? The reason I used Object